# Static Page, need Last and Next links at the bottom

Tags: customization, pages, array

I am new here, I do not have a ton of experience with PHP but if I have a correct block I can work the different functions.  I have a static page, currently, I have it set to display 5 snippets of posts, we have a ton of them on this category, and I need this page to have a line of links with

Newest 1, 2, 3, ... Oldest ...

I cannot get it to display that...

My current code looks like this:

```
 <?php  while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?> 
 <div class="title text-center">    
 <h1><strong><?php the_title();?></strong></h1>
 <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/title.png" title="title-line" alt="title-line">

     </div>
 <div id="no-more-tables" class="legel">
 <?php the_content();?></div>
<?php 
$posts = get_posts(array(
  'posts_per_page'  => 5,
  'category'=>'13'
));
if( $posts ): ?>

<div>
<?php foreach( $posts as $post ): 

    setup_postdata( $post );


    ?>
```

What do I need to add in order to make it do that? I am looking at this example, but it is not making sense to me:

```
<?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : ?>
  <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>

    <?php the_title(); ?>
    <?php the_excerpt(); ?>

  <?php endwhile; ?>
  <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

<?php else : ?>
  <p><?php __('No News'); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I would appreciate any suggestions you may have...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [next\_posts\_link not working in custom loop](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/301048/next-posts-link-not-working-in-custom-loop)

Comment: It does, but now I need to modify the end block...

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work. I've added some explanation to the code in comments:

```
<div class="title text-center">    
    <h1><strong><?php the_title(); ?></strong></h1>
    <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/title.png" title="title-line" alt="title-line">
</div>

<div id="no-more-tables" class="legel">
    <?php the_content(); ?>
</div>

<?php
// Get the page from the url e.g. domain.com/articles?paged=2 would be page 2.
$paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? absint( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) : 1;

// Use WP_Query instead of get_posts() - it is much better for proper queries.
// get_posts() should only really be used for getting a few posts (e.g. related
// articles)
$category_posts = WP_Query(
    array(
        'posts_per_page' => 5,
        'category'       => '13',
        'paged'          => $paged,
    )
);
?>

<?php if ( $category_posts->have_posts() ) : ?>
    <?php while ( $category_posts->have_posts() ) : $category_posts->the_post(); ?>

        <?php the_title(); ?>
        <?php the_content(); ?>

    <?php endwhile; ?>

    <?php
    // Set $big as a massive integer
    $big = 999999999;
    // Echo the pagination (E.g. Prev 1 2 3 3 4 5 Next)
    echo paginate_links(
        array(
            'base'    => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
            'format'  => '?paged=%#%', // Matches your query above
            'current' => max( 1, get_query_var( 'paged' ) ),
            'total'   => $category_posts->max_num_pages,
        )
    );
    ?>

    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); // This must be run after every WP_Query ?>

<?php else : ?>

    No Posts

<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: The reason I was using get_posts() is that I do have several categories that qualify as $posts on the website, look:
http://www.ccdconline.org/ccdc-sound-off/
Everything under the menu blogs qualifies as $posts.

Answer (score 0):

Andy, it did not work, but I think it is because it is not matching to out template's ending, after the setup_postdata( $post ); ... We have this padding:

```
  <div>
    <h3 style="padding-bottom:6px;">
      <a href="<?php echo esc_url(get_permalink($post->ID)); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
    </h3></div>
    <div style="color:#595959;">Posted on: <?php echo date('Y/m/d',strtotime($post->post_date)); //echo date('F j, Y', strtotime($post->post_date)); ?></div>
    <div><?php echo '<p style="padding-bottom:6px !important;">' . get_the_excerpt() . '</p>'?>
    </div>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

<?php endif; ?>
<?php   endwhile;  // End of the loop. ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```